# Page automatically jumping to first link of the website after loading

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, anchor

So, I have this weird behaviour on my [website](https://talesebner.com):

After fully loading the page, it automatically fires the first found link. Currently, it is firing the accessibility Skip button, which has `#main` as `href`. When I delete it, it fires the second one, a pdf of my résumé.

It wasn't like that a week ago, but now it has this weird behaviour. I tested on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge on macOS and also on Windows' Edge. All of them behave the same way.

I will appreciate any help. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the function *clickBlur* (it triggers all the *"a"* tags on the page) used on *window.onload* in *general.js* file. Comment the line where you use the function and try an alternative (CSS) to blur links.